# Solving Variant of FLAMES with equation, when $i$ is given

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, puzzle

This question is based on a *variant* of FLAMES
The rules:

- 6 numbers, from 1-6 are used(to represent F,L,A,M,E,S)
- let natural number $i$ be the sum of letters of names of two people
- there are 5 steps, to the final number, for now, let $i = 10$

  1. first, start from one and move on till 10, the series will be, *1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4*, we end up in 4, so cancel out 4
  2. next, start from 5(the next number), and move on,  the series will be, *5,6,1,2,3,5,6,1,2,3*, we end up in 3,so cancel 3 as well
  3. next, start from 5(the next valid number, which is not canceled), and move on,  the series will be, *5,6,1,2,5,6,1,2,5,6*, we end up in 6,so cancel 6 as well
  4. next, start from 1(the next valid number, which is not canceled), and move on,  the series will be, *1,2,5,1,2,5,1,2,5,1*, we end up in 1,so cancel 1 as well
  5. next, start from 2(the next valid number, which is not canceled), and move on,  the series will be, *2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5*, we end up in 5,so cancel 5 as well

  - we have 2 remaining, **so the answer is *2***

When I tried to solve the answer, in a single-line equation, I noticed the following:

- The first step was easy, the result of the first step is $=((i-1)\mod6)+1$
  For the reason why I am doing +1 then -1, [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803420/14862885)
- The second step is slightly tough, but I drew a table:
  [image]
  here `i` refers to the fixed value of the number of letters, `a` refers to the result from first step $(1)$, i.e. $((i-1)\mod6)+1$,
  here the values inside table are result of step two, when $i,a$ given

  - we notice here that the values repeat vertically, hence the **equation of second step:**   $((((((i-1)\mod5)+1)+a)-1)\mod6)+1$
- The last answer is $=21-(1)-(2)-(3)-(4)-(5)$ ,
  where 21 is the sum of numbers from 1 to 6, and $(1),(2)(3)$... are results of steps 1,2,3... respectively.
  After substituting answer is $=21-4-3-6-1-5=2$.

So I need to know the ***results of steps 3,4,5***, just like how I solved step 1,2, in a single-line equation, that applies to all values of $i$. I think using ***modulo*** is the key to solve, but I don't know how to, please help.

***Note:*** *I mean a single-line equation,all through the Q.S as there is another method of iterative solving,that goes through loops and repeats of the steps just like the humans and solve.Its related to coding,but I need an equation. it will nearly look like
$$
21$$$$
-(((i-1)\mod6)+1)\text{[result of step 1]}$$$$
-(((((((i-1)\mod5)+1)+(((i-1)\mod6)+1))-1)\mod6)+1) $$$$
\text{[result of step 2, substituting a]}$$$$
-...
$$*

Comment: will I never get attention, no vote, not even a -1, or reason for not answering

Comment: Maybe you should have added `puzzle` tag. I think it fits better.

Comment: I added the `puzzle` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variant of counting-out game (FLAMES) that you described is the general case of the *Josephus problem* [1].

Denote by $j_k$ the number that is canceled at step $k = 1, 2, \dots, 6$ during the game. Starting with the letters in order $(1, 2, \dots, 6)$, we cancel the letters in order:
$$
\sigma_i = (j_1, j_2, \dots j_6)
$$

There are $\text{LCM}(\lbrace 1, 2, \dots, 6\rbrace) = 60$ distinct permutations $\sigma_{i}$. Where LCM is the least common multiple of the integers $\lbrace 1, 2, \dots, 6 \rbrace$. Therefore, there are $60$ possible games for $i=1,2, \dots, 60$. For step size $i>60$, we get the same permutation as with $\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ \mathrm{mod}\ #1}(i \Mod{60})$.

The equations you are looking for, follow from the recursive formula:
\begin{equation}
f(n, i, k) = i + f(n - 1, i, k - 1) \Mod{n}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
with initial value:
\begin{equation}
f(n, i, 1) = (i - 1) \Mod{n}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where:

- $n$ is the number of elements (letters),
- $i$ is the step size and
- $f(n, i, k)$ is a function that returns $j_k - 1$.

If we set $n=6$ and develop recursion in (1) until $k=1$ and then apply (2), we get:
\begin{align*}
j_1 &= (i - 1) \Mod{6} + 1\\
j_2 &= (i + (i - 1) \Mod{5}) \Mod{6} + 1\\
j_3 &= (i + (i + (i - 1) \Mod{4}) \Mod{5}) \Mod{6} + 1\\
j_4 &= (i + (i + (i + (i - 1) \Mod{3}) \Mod{4}) \Mod{5}) \Mod{6} + 1\\
j_5 &= (i + (i + (i + (i + (i - 1) \Mod{2}) \Mod{3}) \Mod{4}) \Mod{5}) \Mod{6} + 1\\
j_6 &= (i + (i + (i + (i + (i + (i - 1) \Mod{1}) \Mod{2}) \Mod{3}) \Mod{4}) \Mod{5}) \Mod{6} + 1
\end{align*}

For $i = 10$, we get as in the example you provided:
$$
\sigma_{10} = (4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2)
$$

We can generate these equations in Python for an arbitrary $n$:

```
def f(n, i, k):
    if k == 1:
        return "(i - 1) % " + str(n)
    else:
        return "(i + " + f(n - 1, i, k - 1) + ") % " + str(n)

def sigma(n, i):
    s = []
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        s.append(f(n, i, k) + " + 1")
    return s
```

For the above example with $n = 6$ and $i=10$, running:

```
n, i = 6, 10
s = sigma(n, i)
print([eval(s[k]) for k in range(n)])
```

we collect the above equations in the list `s`, and they evaluate to:

```
[4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2]
```

**[1]**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem

Comment: wow, works amazing, thanks